# How to make a condition in scope in tf.get_collection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a ckpt that I want to restore with tf.train.Saver() and I want to restore all the layer only the last because I want to use the lowest layer for transfer learning here is my code

```
reuse_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope = "")
reuse_vars_dict = dict([(var.name, var) for var in original_saver = 
tf.train.Saver(reuse_vars_dict)
```

and here is how I named my layers

```
48-convolutional/biases:0
48-convolutional/kernel:0
48-convolutional/gamma:0
50-convolutional/biases:0
50-convolutional/kernel:0
```

How can I fixe the scope to not charge the 50's layers meta-data

I use Tensorflow

Please I need help

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do because some code seems to be missing, but can you filter `reuse_vars_dict` to exclude the variables whose name begins with `"50-"`?